# Do encounter-rate modifying effects stack?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-third-generation

Effects such as the Illuminate ability and items such as the White Flute both increase wild encounter rate, however, do these effects stack? For instance, does using a white flute AND making use of Illuminate at the same time have an additional increase of encounter rate over either individually?

Answer (score 1):

> You should note though that Illuminate and a White Flute **don't stack** sadly.

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ShinyPokemon/comments/4ckyoa/i_found_this_a_while_back_birthday_shiny_in_gen/).

Comment: Wish there was a more authoritarian source than a random reddit comment, but I appreciate the lack of information out there.

Comment: I know, that's what I was able to find... I don't have a game to try, empirical method could be the answer.